# Results on $2^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^4}$

Tags: number-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime says:

> H. S. Vandiver proved that $2^{p−1}\equiv1\pmod{p^3}$ if and only if $$1+\frac 13+\cdots+\frac1{p-2}\equiv0\pmod{p^2}.$$

Is there a similar result for $2^{p−1}\equiv1\pmod{p^4}$?

Comment: There are only two primes known for which $2^{p-1}\equiv1\bmod{p^2}$. It seems peculiar to ask about the congruence modulo $p^4$.

Comment: You are correct and there are no known modulo $p^3$ either. Still, Vandiver proved the statement above in 1917. Someone must have worked on it meanwhile.

Comment: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2005-74-250/S0025-5718-04-01666-7/S0025-5718-04-01666-7.pdf